# Printing Even and Odd using two Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I tried the code below. I took this piece of code from some other post which is correct as per the author. But when I try running, it doesn't give me the exact result.

This is mainly to print even and odd values in sequence.

```
public class PrintEvenOddTester {



    public static void main(String ... args){
        Printer print = new Printer(false);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }


}



class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {

    int number=1;
    Printer print;

    TaskEvenOdd(Printer print){
        this.print = print;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Run method");
        while(number<10){

            if(number%2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Number is :"+ number);
                print.printEven(number);
                number+=2;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Number is :"+ number);
                print.printOdd(number);
                number+=2;
            }
        }

      }

    }

class Printer {

    boolean isOdd;

    Printer(boolean isOdd){
        this.isOdd = isOdd;
    }

    synchronized void printEven(int number) {

        while(isOdd){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even:"+number);
        isOdd = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void printOdd(int number) {
        while(!isOdd){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Odd:"+number);
        isOdd = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

Can someone help me in fixing this?

**EDIT**
Expected result:
Odd:1
Even:2
Odd:3
Even:4
Odd:5
Even:6
Odd:7
Even:8
Odd:9

Comment: What is the actual result and what is your expected result?

Comment: number starts at 1, and you only ever increment it by 2. Therefore it will never be even.

Comment: This is not a debugging service...

Comment: For every student who comes here:  Please tell your instructor that while this exercise might teach you something about _how_ to control threads, it is a really horrible example of _why_ to use threads.  If you want a program to do certain things (e.g., print numbers) in a certain order (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...); then the absolutely _best_ way to do it is to do those things in a single thread.  Every multi-threaded program requires _some_ synchronization between threads, but the more synchronization you use, the less benefit you get from threading.  This program actually gets _negative_ benefit.

Comment: There is no reason why the threads should print numbers in alternation, even leaving aside the error about the increment. Your expectations are astray, as is the uncited 'some other piece of code'. SO is not a validation service for arbitrary Internet junk.

Comment: Check it out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014237/1404798

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Found the solution. Someone looking for solution to this problem can refer :-)

```
public class PrintEvenOddTester {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Printer print = new Printer();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print, 10, false));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print, 10, true));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}

class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {

    private int max;
    private Printer print;
    private boolean isEvenNumber;

    TaskEvenOdd(Printer print, int max, boolean isEvenNumber) {
        this.print = print;
        this.max = max;
        this.isEvenNumber = isEvenNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //System.out.println("Run method");
        int number = isEvenNumber == true ? 2 : 1;
        while (number <= max) {

            if (isEvenNumber) {
                //System.out.println("Even :"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                print.printEven(number);
                //number+=2;
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Odd :"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                print.printOdd(number);
                // number+=2;
            }
            number += 2;
        }

    }

}

class Printer {

    boolean isOdd = false;

    synchronized void printEven(int number) {

        while (isOdd == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even:" + number);
        isOdd = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void printOdd(int number) {
        while (isOdd == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Odd:" + number);
        isOdd = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

**This gives output like:**

```
Odd:1
Even:2
Odd:3
Even:4
Odd:5
Even:6
Odd:7
Even:8
Odd:9
Even:10
```

Comment: Answer is not correct and cannot be correct without synchronization or a lock of some kind.

Comment: How do you control that the "Odd" thread starts before "Even" thread has started ? Would you ask the "Even" thread to sleep as it starts ??

Comment: Programitcally your code will give the correct output, however the code is not written in logical way.
For eg.
While you printing even number, the thread should go in waiting state if isOdd is true. But in your code in printEven method the thread will go in to waiting state if isOdd is false.

Comment: how even thread is started after odd, thread schduleing is not gurantted and here the we are not specifiying any delay for even worker

Comment: @NarendraJaggi
See "boolean isOdd = false;" in Printer class, it ensures that odd number will be printed first, it's not about which thread started first

Answer (score 23):

Use this following very simple JAVA 8 Runnable Class feature

```
public class MultiThreadExample {

static AtomicInteger atomicNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable print = () -> {
        while (atomicNumber.get() < 10) {
            synchronized (atomicNumber) {
                if ((atomicNumber.get() % 2 == 0) && "Even".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                    System.out.println("Even" + ":" + atomicNumber.getAndIncrement());
                } //else if ((atomicNumber.get() % 2 != 0) && "Odd".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                   else {System.out.println("Odd" + ":" + atomicNumber.getAndIncrement());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(print);
    t1.setName("Even");
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(print);
    t2.setName("Odd");
    t2.start();

}
}
```

Comment: What is te use of AtomicBoolean here?

Comment: Insted of else if ((atomicNumber.get() % 2 != 0) && "Odd".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName()))  you can simply use else block. Second condition was not required.

Comment: Where is AtomicBoolean ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the code which I made it work through a single class

```
package com.learn.thread;

public class PrintNumbers extends Thread {
volatile static int i = 1;
Object lock;

PrintNumbers(Object lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
}

public static void main(String ar[]) {
    Object obj = new Object();
    // This constructor is required for the identification of wait/notify
    // communication
    PrintNumbers odd = new PrintNumbers(obj);
    PrintNumbers even = new PrintNumbers(obj);
    odd.setName("Odd");
    even.setName("Even");
    odd.start();
    even.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (i <= 10) {
        if (i % 2 == 0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Even")) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - "
                        + i);
                i++;
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 1 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Odd")) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - "
                        + i);
                i++;
                lock.notify();
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Odd - 1
Even - 2
Odd - 3
Even - 4
Odd - 5
Even - 6
Odd - 7
Even - 8
Odd - 9
Even - 10
Odd - 11
```

Comment: 1) What is the use of explicit lock ...we can use this also ..                         2) What is the use of wait and notify we can still get the same output ...

Answer (score 5):

```
   private Object lock = new Object();
   private volatile boolean isOdd = false;


    public void generateEvenNumbers(int number) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
            while (isOdd == false) 
            {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            isOdd = false;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void generateOddNumbers(int number) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
            while (isOdd == true) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            isOdd = true;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest solution for this problem.

```
public class OddEven implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t2")) {
                    try {
                        notifyAll();
                        System.out.println("Even Thread : " + i);
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (i % 2 != 0
                        && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")) {
                    try {
                        notifyAll();
                        System.out.println("Odd Thread : " + i);
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OddEven obj = new OddEven();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simplest Solution!!**

```
public class OddEvenWithThread {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new OddEvenRunnable(0), "Even Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new OddEvenRunnable(1), "Odd Thread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class OddEvenRunnable implements Runnable {
    Integer evenflag;
    static Integer number = 1;
    static Object lock = new Object();

    OddEvenRunnable(Integer evenFlag) {
        this.evenflag = evenFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (number < 10) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    while (number % 2 != evenflag) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + number);
                number++;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The same can be done with Lock interface:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class NumberPrinter implements Runnable {
    private Lock lock;
    private Condition condition;
    private String type;
    private static boolean oddTurn = true;

    public NumberPrinter(String type, Lock lock, Condition condition) {
        this.type = type;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = type.equals("odd") ? 1 : 2;
        while (i <= 10) {
            if (type.equals("odd"))
                printOdd(i);
            if (type.equals("even"))
                printEven(i);
            i = i + 2;
        }
    }

    private void printOdd(int i) {
        // synchronized (lock) {
        lock.lock();
        while (!oddTurn) {
            try {
                // lock.wait();
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(type + " " + i);
        oddTurn = false;
        // lock.notifyAll();
        condition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    // }

    private void printEven(int i) {
        // synchronized (lock) {
        lock.lock();
        while (oddTurn) {
            try {
                // lock.wait();
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(type + " " + i);
        oddTurn = true;
        // lock.notifyAll();
        condition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        Thread odd = new Thread(new NumberPrinter("odd", lock, condition));
        Thread even = new Thread(new NumberPrinter("even", lock, condition));
        odd.start();
        even.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This code will also work fine.**

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable {

    private static boolean evenFlag = true;

    public synchronized void run() {
        if (evenFlag == true) {
            printEven();
        } else {
           printOdd();
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(i+""+Thread.currentThread());
        }
        evenFlag = false;
    }

    public  void printOdd() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(i+""+Thread.currentThread());
        }
        evenFlag = true;
    }
}

public class OddEvenDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        Thread td1 = new Thread(t1);
        Thread td2 = new Thread(t1);
        td1.start();
        td2.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Should'nt the evenFlag assignments be inside the loops?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class PrintEvenOddTester {
      public static void main(String ... args){
            Printer print = new Printer(false);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print, "Thread1", new AtomicInteger(1)));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print,"Thread2" , new AtomicInteger(2)));
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
}

class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {
    Printer print;
    String name;
    AtomicInteger number;
    TaskEvenOdd(Printer print, String name, AtomicInteger number){
        this.print = print;
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Run method");
        while(number.get()<10){

            if(number.get()%2 == 0){
                print.printEven(number.get(),name);
            }
            else {
                print.printOdd(number.get(),name);
            }
            number.addAndGet(2);
        }

      }

    }



class Printer {
    boolean isEven;

    public Printer() {  }

    public Printer(boolean isEven) {
        this.isEven = isEven;
    }

    synchronized void printEven(int number, String name) {

        while (!isEven) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(name+": Even:" + number);
        isEven = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    synchronized void printOdd(int number, String name) {
        while (isEven) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(name+": Odd:" + number);
        isEven = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer, to make your point clear.

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer, to make your point clear².

Answer (score 1):

The other question was closed as a duplicate of this one. I think we can safely get rid of "even or odd" problem and use the `wait/notify` construct as follows:

```
public class WaitNotifyDemoEvenOddThreads {
    /**
     * A transfer object, only use with proper client side locking!
     */
    static final class LastNumber {
        int num;
        final int limit;

        LastNumber(int num, int limit) {
            this.num = num;
            this.limit = limit;
        }
    }

    static final class NumberPrinter implements Runnable {
        private final LastNumber last;
        private final int init;

        NumberPrinter(LastNumber last, int init) {
            this.last = last;
            this.init = init;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = init;
            synchronized (last) {
                while (i <= last.limit) {
                    while (last.num != i) {
                        try {
                            last.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " prints: " + i);
                    last.num = i + 1;
                    i += 2;
                    last.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LastNumber last = new LastNumber(0, 10); // or 0, 1000
        NumberPrinter odd = new NumberPrinter(last, 1);
        NumberPrinter even = new NumberPrinter(last, 0);
        new Thread(odd, "o").start();
        new Thread(even, "e").start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Simpler Version in Java 8:

public class EvenOddPrinter {
    static boolean flag = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable odd = () -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10;) {
                if(EvenOddPrinter.flag) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i+=2;
                    EvenOddPrinter.flag = !EvenOddPrinter.flag;
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable even = () -> {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10;) {
                if(!EvenOddPrinter.flag) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i+=2;
                    EvenOddPrinter.flag = !EvenOddPrinter.flag;
                }
            }
        };

         Thread t1 = new Thread(odd, "Odd");
         Thread t2 = new Thread(even, "Even");
         t1.start();
         t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using 2 Threads with 2 different runnable, besides when I try to run sometimes it stuck in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
package pkgscjp;

public class OddPrint implements Runnable {

    public static boolean flag = true;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 99;) {
            if (flag) {
                System.out.println(i);
                flag = false;
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
    }

}


package pkgscjp;

public class EvenPrint implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100;) {
            if (!OddPrint.flag) {
                System.out.println(i);
                OddPrint.flag = true;
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }

    }
}


package pkgscjp;

public class NaturalNumberThreadMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EvenPrint ep = new EvenPrint();
        OddPrint op = new OddPrint();
        Thread te = new Thread(ep);
        Thread to = new Thread(op);
        to.start();
        te.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it this way, while printing using two threads we cannot predict the sequence which thread
   would get executed first so to overcome this situation we have to synchronize the shared resource,in
   my case the print function which two threads are trying to access.

```
class Printoddeven{

    public synchronized void print(String msg) {
        try {
            if(msg.equals("Even")) {
                for(int i=0;i<=10;i+=2) {
                    System.out.println(msg+" "+i);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    notify();
                    wait();
                }
            } else {
                for(int i=1;i<=10;i+=2) {
                    System.out.println(msg+" "+i);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    notify();
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class PrintOdd extends Thread{
    Printoddeven oddeven;
    public PrintOdd(Printoddeven oddeven){
        this.oddeven=oddeven;
    }

    public void run(){
        oddeven.print("ODD");
    }
}

class PrintEven extends Thread{
    Printoddeven oddeven;
    public PrintEven(Printoddeven oddeven){
        this.oddeven=oddeven;
    }

    public void run(){
        oddeven.print("Even");
    }
}



public class mainclass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printoddeven obj = new Printoddeven();//only one object  
        PrintEven t1=new PrintEven(obj);  
        PrintOdd t2=new PrintOdd(obj);  
        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem. I have two classes implementing `Runnable`, one prints odd sequence and the other prints even. I have an instance of `Object`, that I use for lock. I initialize the two classes with the same object. There is a `synchronized block` inside the run method of the two classes, where, inside a loop, each method prints one of the numbers, notifies the other thread, waiting for lock on the same object and then itself waits for the same lock again.

The classes :

```
public class PrintEven implements Runnable{
private Object lock;
public PrintEven(Object lock) {
    this.lock =  lock;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i+=2) {
            System.out.println("EVEN:="+i);
            lock.notify();
            try {
                //if(i!=10) lock.wait();
                lock.wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

  }
}


public class PrintOdd implements Runnable {
private Object lock;
public PrintOdd(Object lock) {
    this.lock =  lock;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i+=2) {
            System.out.println("ODD:="+i);
            lock.notify();
            try {
                //if(i!=9) lock.wait();
                lock.wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public class PrintEvenOdd {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Object lock = new Object(); 
    Thread thread1 =  new Thread(new PrintOdd(lock));
    Thread thread2 =  new Thread(new PrintEven(lock));
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
}
```

The upper limit in my example is 10. Once the odd thread prints 9 or the even thread prints 10, then we don't need any of the threads to wait any more. So, we can handle that using one `if-block`. Or, we can use the overloaded `wait(long timeout)` method for the wait to be timed out.
One flaw here though. With this code, we cannot guarantee which thread will start execution first.

Another example, using Lock and Condition

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockConditionOddEven {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lock lock =  new ReentrantLock();
    Condition evenCondition = lock.newCondition();
    Condition oddCondition = lock.newCondition();
    Thread evenThread =  new Thread(new EvenPrinter(10, lock, evenCondition, oddCondition));
    Thread oddThread =  new Thread(new OddPrinter(10, lock, evenCondition, oddCondition));
    oddThread.start();
    evenThread.start();
}

static class OddPrinter implements Runnable{
    int i = 1;
    int limit;
    Lock lock;
    Condition evenCondition;
    Condition oddCondition;

    public OddPrinter(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public OddPrinter(int limit, Lock lock, Condition evenCondition, Condition oddCondition) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.evenCondition = evenCondition;
        this.oddCondition = oddCondition;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while( i <=limit) {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("Odd:"+i);
            evenCondition.signal();
            i+=2;
            try {
                oddCondition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}

static class EvenPrinter implements Runnable{
    int i = 2;
    int limit;
    Lock lock;
    Condition evenCondition;
    Condition oddCondition;

    public EvenPrinter(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }


    public EvenPrinter(int limit, Lock lock, Condition evenCondition, Condition oddCondition) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.evenCondition = evenCondition;
        this.oddCondition = oddCondition;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while( i <=limit) {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("Even:"+i);
            i+=2;
            oddCondition.signal();
            try {
                evenCondition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code to print odd even no alternatively using wait and notify mechanism. I have restrict the limit of numbers to print 1 to 50.

```
public class NotifyTest {
    Object ob=new Object(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    NotifyTest nt=new NotifyTest();

    even e=new even(nt.ob);     
    odd o=new odd(nt.ob);

    Thread t1=new Thread(e);
    Thread t2=new Thread(o);

    t1.start();     
    t2.start();
    }
}    

class even implements Runnable
{
    Object lock;        
    int i=2;

    public even(Object ob)
    {
        this.lock=ob;       
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        while(i<=50)
        {
            synchronized (lock) {               
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Even Thread Name-->>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Value-->>" + i);
            i=i+2;              
        }           
    }       
} 

class odd implements Runnable
{

    Object lock;
    int i=1;    

    public odd(Object ob)
    {
        this.lock=ob;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(i<=49)
        {
            synchronized (lock) {               
            System.out.println("Odd Thread Name-->>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Value-->>" + i);
            i=i+2;              
            lock.notify();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my implementation using 2 Semaphores.

1. Odd Semaphore with permit 1.
2. Even Semaphore with permit 0.
3. Pass the two Semaphores to both threads as following signature (my, other):-
4. To Odd thread pass in the order (odd, even)
5. To Even thread pass in this order (even, odd)
6. run() method logic is my.acquireUninterruptibly() -> Print -> other.release()
7. In Even thread as even Sema is 0 it will block.
8. In Odd thread as odd Sema is available (init to 1) this will print 1 and then release even Sema allowing Even thread to run.
9. Even thread runs prints 2 and release odd Sema allowing Odd thread to run.

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


   public class EvenOdd {
   private final static String ODD = "ODD";
   private final static String EVEN = "EVEN";
   private final static int MAX_ITERATIONS = 10;

   public static class EvenOddThread implements Runnable {     
       private String mType;
       private int  mNum;
       private Semaphore mMySema;
       private Semaphore mOtherSema;

       public EvenOddThread(String str, Semaphore mine, Semaphore other) {
           mType = str;
           mMySema = mine;//new Semaphore(1); // start out as unlocked
           mOtherSema = other;//new Semaphore(0);
           if(str.equals(ODD)) {
               mNum = 1;
           }
           else {
               mNum = 2;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {         

               for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
                   mMySema.acquireUninterruptibly();
                   if (mType.equals(ODD)) {
                       System.out.println("Odd Thread - " + mNum);
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("Even Thread - " + mNum);
                   }
                   mNum += 2;
                   mOtherSema.release();
               }           
       }

   }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           Semaphore odd = new Semaphore(1);
           Semaphore even = new Semaphore(0);

           System.out.println("Start!!!");
           System.out.println();

           Thread tOdd = new Thread(new EvenOddThread(ODD, 
                                    odd, 
                                    even));
           Thread tEven = new Thread(new EvenOddThread(EVEN, 
                                    even, 
                                    odd));

           tOdd.start();
           tEven.start();

           tOdd.join();
           tEven.join();

           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Done!!!");
       }       

   }
   ```

Following is the output:-

```
Start!!!

Odd Thread - 1
Even Thread - 2
Odd Thread - 3
Even Thread - 4
Odd Thread - 5
Even Thread - 6
Odd Thread - 7
Even Thread - 8
Odd Thread - 9
Even Thread - 10
Odd Thread - 11
Even Thread - 12
Odd Thread - 13
Even Thread - 14
Odd Thread - 15
Even Thread - 16
Odd Thread - 17
Even Thread - 18
Odd Thread - 19
Even Thread - 20

Done!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solutions being provided have unnecessarily added stuff and does not use semaphores to its full potential. Here's what my solution is.

```
package com.test.threads;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class EvenOddThreadTest {

    public static int MAX = 100;
    public static Integer number = new Integer(0);

    //Unlocked state
    public Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    class PrinterThread extends Thread {

        int start = 0;
        String name;

        PrinterThread(String name ,int start) {
            this.start = start;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(start < MAX){
                    // try to acquire the number of semaphore equal to your value
                    // and if you do not get it then wait for it.
                semaphore.acquire(start);
                System.out.println(name + " : " + start);
                // prepare for the next iteration.
                start+=2;
                // release one less than what you need to print in the next iteration.
                // This will release the other thread which is waiting to print the next number.
                semaphore.release(start-1);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EvenOddThreadTest test = new EvenOddThreadTest();
        PrinterThread a = test.new PrinterThread("Even",1);
        PrinterThread b = test.new PrinterThread("Odd", 2);
        try {
            a.start();
            b.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example;

public class MyClass  {
    static int mycount=0;
    static Thread t;
    static Thread t2;
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.print(mycount++ + " even \n");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mycount>25)
                    System.exit(0);
                run();
            }
        });
        t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.print(mycount++ + " odd \n");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mycount>26)
                    System.exit(0);
                run();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution using single class

```
package com.fursa.threads;

   public class PrintNumbers extends Thread {

     Object lock;

    PrintNumbers(Object lock) {
         this.lock = lock;
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        // This constructor is required for the identification of wait/notify
        // communication
        PrintNumbers odd = new PrintNumbers(obj);
        PrintNumbers even = new PrintNumbers(obj);
        odd.setName("Odd");
        even.setName("Even");
        even.start();
        odd.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) {

            synchronized (lock) {

                if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Even")) {

                    if(i % 2 == 0 ){
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - "+ i);
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                   
                    else if (i % 2 != 0 ) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }

                if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Odd")) {

                    if(i % 2 == 1 ){
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - "+ i);
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                   
                    else if (i % 2 != 1 ) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the output with creating two anonymous thread classes.

```
package practice;

class Display {
    boolean isEven = false;

    synchronized public void printEven(int number) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEven)
            wait();
        System.out.println("Even : " + number);
        isEven = true;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized public void printOdd(int number) throws InterruptedException {
        while (!isEven)
            wait();
        System.out.println("Odd : " + number);
        isEven = false;
        notify();
    }
}

public class OddEven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Display disp = new Display();


        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int num = 0;
                for (int i = num; i <= 10; i += 2) {
                    try {
                        disp.printEven(i);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int num = 1;
                for (int i = num; i <= 10; i += 2) {
                    try {
                        disp.printOdd(i);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived using Lock and Condition :

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class EvenOddThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Printer p = new Printer();
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new PrintThread(p,false),"Odd  :");
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new PrintThread(p,true),"Even :");
        oddThread.start();
        evenThread.start();
    }

}

class PrintThread implements Runnable{
    Printer p;
    boolean isEven = false;

    PrintThread(Printer p, boolean isEven){
        this.p = p;
        this.isEven = isEven;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = (isEven==true) ? 2 : 1;
        while(i < 10 ){
            if(isEven){
                p.printEven(i);
            }else{
                p.printOdd(i);
            }
            i=i+2;
        }
    }
}

class Printer{

    boolean isEven = true;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condEven = lock.newCondition();
    Condition condOdd = lock.newCondition();

    public void printEven(int no){
        lock.lock();
        while(isEven==true){
            try {
                condEven.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +no);
        isEven = true;
        condOdd.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void printOdd(int no){
        lock.lock();
        while(isEven==false){
            try {
                condOdd.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +no);
        isEven = false;
        condEven.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class to print odd Even number

```
public class PrintOddEven implements Runnable {

    private int max;
    private int number;

    public  PrintOddEven(int max_number,int number) {
        max = max_number;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while(number<=max)
        {
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("odd"))
            {
                try {
                    printOdd();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    printEven();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


    }

    public synchronized void printOdd() throws InterruptedException
    {

        if(number%2==0)
        {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println(number+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        number++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void printEven() throws InterruptedException
    {

        if(number%2!=0)
        {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println(number+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        number++;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

Driver Program

```
public class OddEvenThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintOddEven printer = new PrintOddEven(10,1);  
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(printer,"odd");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread (printer,"even");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreadEvenOdd {
  static int cnt=0;
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
          while(cnt<101) {
            if(cnt%2==0) {
              System.out.print(cnt+" ");
              cnt++;
            }
            notifyAll();
          }
        }
      }

    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
          while(cnt<101) {
            if(cnt%2==1) {
              System.out.print(cnt+" ");
              cnt++;
            }
            notifyAll();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class OddAndEvenThreadProblems {
            private static Integer i = 0;

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new EvenClass().start();
                new OddClass().start();

            }

            public static class EvenClass extends Thread {

                public void run() {
                    while (i < 10) {
                        synchronized (i) {
                            if (i % 2 == 0 ) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    System.out.println(" EvenClass " + i);
                                    i = i + 1;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public static class OddClass extends Thread {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (i < 10) {
                        synchronized (i) {
                            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    System.out.println(" OddClass  " + i);
                                    i = i + 1;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }





OUTPUT will be :- 

 EvenClass 0
 OddClass  1
 EvenClass 2
 OddClass  3
 EvenClass 4
 OddClass  5
 EvenClass 6
 OddClass  7
 EvenClass 8
 OddClass  9
```

Comment: Some words of explanation are appreciated on stack overflow.

Comment: Printing odd and even number by two Threads can be done very easily.
We don't need any semaphores for this.We just need a static variable which can be accessed by both the threads . We can check the value of this reference variable , if the variable is an even number then it will be printed by the evenThread else it will be printed by the odd thread. But we have to keep in mind one thing that the variable should be  synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

```
package example;

public class PrintSeqTwoThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object mutex = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10;) {
                    synchronized (mutex) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + j);
                        j = j + 2;
                        mutex.notify();
                        try {
                            mutex.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 1; j < 10;) {
                    synchronized (mutex) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + j);
                        j = j + 2;
                        mutex.notify();
                        try {
                            mutex.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to print odd and even number in a proper order along with desired messages.

```
package practice;


class Test {

  private static boolean oddFlag = true;
  int count = 1;

  private void oddPrinter() {
    synchronized (this) {
      while(true) {
        try {
          if(count < 10) {
            if(oddFlag) {
              Thread.sleep(500);
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + count++);
              oddFlag = !oddFlag;
              notifyAll();
            }
            else {
              wait();
            }
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Odd Thread finished");
            notify();
            break;
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void evenPrinter() {
    synchronized (this) {
      while (true) {
        try {
          if(count < 10) {
            if(!oddFlag) {
              Thread.sleep(500);
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + count++);
              oddFlag = !oddFlag;
              notify();
            }
            else {
              wait();
            }
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Even Thread finished");
            notify();
            break;
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    final Test test = new Test();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        test.oddPrinter();
      }
    }, "Thread 1");

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        test.evenPrinter();
      }
    }, "Thread 2");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    System.out.println("Main thread finished");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand most of the codes that were here so I wrote myself one, maybe it helps someone like me:

NOTE: This does not use separate print even and odd method. One method print() does it all.

```
public class test {

    private static int START_INT = 1;
    private static int STOP_INT = 10;
    private static String THREAD_1 = "Thread A";
    private static String THREAD_2 = "Thread B";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchronizedRepository syncRep = new SynchronizedRepository(START_INT,STOP_INT);
        Runnable r1 = new EvenOddWorker(THREAD_1,syncRep);
        Runnable r2 = new EvenOddWorker(THREAD_2,syncRep);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1, THREAD_1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2, THREAD_2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}




public class SynchronizedRepository {
    private volatile int number;
    private volatile boolean isSlotEven;
    private int startNumber;
    private int stopNumber;

    public SynchronizedRepository(int startNumber, int stopNumber) {
        super();
        this.number = startNumber;
        this.isSlotEven = startNumber%2==0;
        this.startNumber = startNumber;
        this.stopNumber = stopNumber;
    }


    public synchronized void print(String threadName) {
        try {
            for(int i=startNumber; i<=stopNumber/2; i++){
                if ((isSlotEven && number % 2 == 0)||
                        (!isSlotEven && number % 2 != 0)){
                    System.out.println(threadName + " "+ number);
                    isSlotEven = !isSlotEven;
                    number++;
                }
                notifyAll();
                wait();
            }
            notifyAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}



public class EvenOddWorker implements Runnable {

    private String threadName;
    private SynchronizedRepository syncRep;

    public EvenOddWorker(String threadName, SynchronizedRepository syncRep) {
        super();
        this.threadName = threadName;
        this.syncRep = syncRep;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        syncRep.print(threadName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution :)

```
package com.code.threads;

public class PrintOddEven extends Thread {

    private Object lock;
    static volatile int count = 1;

    PrintOddEven(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        while(count <= 10) {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                synchronized(lock){
                    System.out.println("Even - " + count);
                    ++count;
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                synchronized(lock){
                    System.out.println("Odd - " + count);
                    ++count;
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        PrintOddEven even = new PrintOddEven(obj);
        PrintOddEven odd = new PrintOddEven(obj);

        even.start();
        odd.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int N = 100;
        PrintingThread oddNumberThread = new PrintingThread(N - 1);
        PrintingThread evenNumberThread = new PrintingThread(N);
        oddNumberThread.start();
        // make sure that even thread only start after odd thread
        while (!evenNumberThread.isAlive()) {
            if(oddNumberThread.isAlive()) {
                evenNumberThread.start();
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }

    }
}

class PrintingThread extends Thread {
    private static final Object object = new Object(); // lock for both threads
    final int N;
    // N determines whether given thread is even or odd
    PrintingThread(int N) {
        this.N = N;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (object) {
            int start = N % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1; // if N is odd start from 1 else start from 0
            for (int i = start; i <= N; i = i + 2) {
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    object.notify(); // will notify waiting thread
                    object.wait(); // will make current thread wait
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PrintNumberTask implements Runnable {
Integer count;
Object lock;

PrintNumberTask(int i, Object object) {
    this.count = i;
    this.lock = object;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (count <= 10) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(count);
                count++;
                lock.notify();
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(count);
                count++;
                lock.notify();
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Some explanation about the code is always helpful for the author or any other user with a similar question for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me (Java 8 and above used Lamda expression)

```
public class EvenOddUsingThread {

    static int number = 100;
    static int counter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenOddUsingThread eod = new EvenOddUsingThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> eod.printOdd());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> eod.printEven());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void printOdd() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (counter < number) {
                if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                // Print the number
                System.out.println(counter + " Thread Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                // Increment counter
                counter++;
                // Notify to second thread
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (counter < number) {
                if (counter % 2 == 1) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }
                // Print the number
                System.out.println(counter + " Thread Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                // Increment counter
                counter++;
                // Notify to second thread
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is using java 8 completable future and executor service to print even and odd numbers using two threads.

```
ExecutorService firstExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setName("first");
        return t;
    });

    ExecutorService secondExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setName("second");
        return t;
    });

    IntStream.range(1, 101).forEach(num -> {

        CompletableFuture<Integer> thenApplyAsync = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(num).thenApplyAsync(x -> {

            if (x % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println(x + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
            return num;
        }, firstExecutorService);

        thenApplyAsync.join();

        CompletableFuture<Integer> thenApplyAsync2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(num).thenApplyAsync(x -> {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
            return num;
        }, secondExecutorService);

        thenApplyAsync2.join();
    });

    firstExecutorService.shutdown();
    secondExecutorService.shutdown();
```

The below is the console log of it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can print odd and even using two separate threads using `CompletableFuture` as well:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class OddEvenBy2Thread {

    private static Object object = new Object();

    private static IntPredicate evenCondition = e -> e % 2 == 0;
    private static IntPredicate oddCondition = e -> e % 2 != 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Odd number printer
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> OddEvenBy2Thread.printNumber(oddCondition));

        // Even number printer
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> OddEvenBy2Thread.printNumber(evenCondition));

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public static void printNumber(IntPredicate condition){
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).filter(condition).forEach(OddEvenBy2Thread::execute);
    }

    public static void execute(int num){
        synchronized (object){
            try{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+num);
                object.notify();
                object.wait();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public class EvenOddex {

```
public static class print {

    int n;
    boolean isOdd = false;

    synchronized public void printEven(int n) {

        while (isOdd) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EvenOddex.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + n + "\n");

        isOdd = true;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized public void printOdd(int n) {
        while (!isOdd) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EvenOddex.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + n + "\n");
        isOdd = false;
        notify();



    }
}

public static class even extends Thread {

    print po;

    even(print po) {

        this.po = po;

        new Thread(this, "Even").start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if ((j % 2) == 0) {
                po.printEven(j);
            }
        }

    }
}

public static class odd extends Thread {

    print po;

    odd(print po) {

        this.po = po;
        new Thread(this, "Odd").start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                po.printOdd(i);
            }
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    print po = new print();
    new even(po);
    new odd(po);

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Multi extends Thread{  
    public static int a;
    static{a=1;}
    public void run(){  
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
        System.out.println("Thread Id  "+this.getId()+"  Value "+a++);
        try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  

        }  
    }  
public static void main(String args[]){  
       Multi t1=new Multi();  
       Multi t2=new Multi();  

      t1.start();  
      t2.start();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: The correctness of your program is dependent upon 'Thread.sleep();' that you have written over there. It will give unpredictable results. The idea is to create a program that will yield the desired result with certainty.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class PrintOddEven {
private static class PrinterThread extends Thread {

    private static int current = 0;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    private PrinterThread(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                try {
                    LOCK.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (current < number) {
                    System.out.println(name + ++current);
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    int number;
    String name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PrinterThread("thread1 : ", 20).start();
    new PrinterThread("thread2 : ", 20).start();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public class Solution {

```
 static class NumberGenerator{

     private static volatile boolean printEvenNumber = false;


     public  void printEvenNumber(int i) {
         synchronized (this) {
             if(!printEvenNumber) {
                 try {
                     wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(i);
             printEvenNumber = !printEvenNumber;
             notify();
         }
     }

     public  void printOddNumber(int i ) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if(printEvenNumber) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(i);
                printEvenNumber = !printEvenNumber;
                notify();
            }
     }

}

static  class OddNumberGenerator implements Runnable{
    private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

    public OddNumberGenerator(NumberGenerator numberGenerator) {
        this.numberGenerator = numberGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i  = 1; i <100; i = i + 2) {
            numberGenerator.printOddNumber(i);
        }
    }
}

static class EvenNumberGenerator implements Runnable {
    private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

    public EvenNumberGenerator(NumberGenerator numberGenerator) {
        this.numberGenerator = numberGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i =  i + 2) {
           numberGenerator.printEvenNumber(i);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberGenerator ng = new NumberGenerator();
    OddNumberGenerator oddNumberGenerator = new OddNumberGenerator(ng);
    EvenNumberGenerator evenNumberGenerator = new EvenNumberGenerator(ng);
    new Thread(oddNumberGenerator).start();
    new Thread(evenNumberGenerator).start();

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
package programs.multithreading;

public class PrintOddEvenNoInSequence {

final int upto;
final PrintOddEvenNoInSequence obj;
volatile boolean oddFlag,evenFlag;
public PrintOddEvenNoInSequence(int upto){
    this.upto = upto;
    obj = this;
    oddFlag = true;
    evenFlag = false;
}
void printInSequence(){

    Thread odd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1; i <= upto; i = i + 2){
                synchronized (obj) {
                    while(!oddFlag){
                        try {
                            obj.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Odd:"+i);
                    oddFlag = false;
                    evenFlag = true;
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread even = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 2; i <= upto; i = i + 2){
                synchronized (obj) {
                    while(!evenFlag){
                        try {
                            obj.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Even:"+i);
                    oddFlag = true;
                    evenFlag = false;
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    odd.start();
    even.start();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PrintOddEvenNoInSequence(100).printInSequence();
}
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

See the Clean implementation

```
public class PrintOddEvenByTwoThreads {
    static int number = 1;
    static Thread odd;
    static Thread even;
    static int max = 10;

    static class OddThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (number <= max) {
                if (number % 2 == 1) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "" + number++);
                } else {

                    synchronized (odd) {
                        synchronized (even) {
                            even.notify();
                        }
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class EvenThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (number <= max) {
                if (number % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "" + number++);
                } else {

                    synchronized (even) {
                        synchronized (odd) {
                            odd.notify();
                        }
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        odd = new OddThread();
        even = new EvenThread();
        odd.start();
        even.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1- The number is initialized with 1 and `isOdd` flag is set to *false*.  set `isOdd` to *true*

2-  Increment should be by 1 (not by 2) i.e  `number+=1`;

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


public class PrintOddAndEven {

private static class OddThread extends Thread {
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    private Semaphore otherSemaphore;
    private int value = 1;

    public  OddThread(Semaphore semaphore, Semaphore otherSemaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.otherSemaphore = otherSemaphore;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (value <= 100) {
            try {
                // Acquire odd semaphore
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(" Odd Thread " + value + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            } catch (InterruptedException excetion) {
                excetion.printStackTrace();
            }
            value = value + 2;
            // Release odd semaphore
            otherSemaphore.release();
        }
    }
}


private static class EvenThread extends Thread {
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    private Semaphore otherSemaphore;

    private int value = 2;

    public  EvenThread(Semaphore semaphore, Semaphore otherSemaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.otherSemaphore = otherSemaphore;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (value <= 100) {
            try {
                // Acquire even semaphore
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(" Even Thread " + value + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            } catch (InterruptedException excetion) {
                excetion.printStackTrace();
            }
            value = value + 2;
            // Release odd semaphore
            otherSemaphore.release();
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initialize oddSemaphore with permit 1
    Semaphore oddSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    //Initialize evenSempahore with permit 0
    Semaphore evenSempahore = new Semaphore(0);
    OddThread oddThread = new OddThread(oddSemaphore, evenSempahore);
    EvenThread evenThread = new EvenThread(evenSempahore, oddSemaphore);
    oddThread.start();
    evenThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Added comments to the code. Program prints 1 to 100, shared between two threads.

Answer (score -2):

Simple Solution below:-

```
package com.test;

class MyThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i=1;
        while(true) {
            String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if(name.equals("task1") && i%2!=0) {
                System.out.println(name+"::::"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if(name.equals("task2") && i%2==0){
                System.out.println(name+"::::"+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThread task1=new MyThread();
        MyThread task2=new MyThread();

        Thread t1=new Thread(task1,"task1");
        Thread t2=new Thread(task2,"task2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}
```