# Opposite Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I want to make Opposite Thread in java.

If `Thread A` is running, then `Thread B` is waiting.
The other way, `Thread B` is running, then `Thread A` is waiting.

```
A : -----　　　　　　　------------------　　　　　-----------

B : 　　　------------　　　　　　　　　　--------
```

I want to write code with `wait()`, notify `function(not suspend(), resume)`
But it is very difficult for me.

Help me

Comment: ok.. where are you stucked? What do you think is difficult? Did you tried solving?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Even and Odd using two Threads in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689449/printing-even-and-odd-using-two-threads-in-java)

Comment: Documentation is your friend - start with the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and try experiments with some code. It'll work a lot better than us trying to explain these concepts to you in a very broad question like this.  Come back if you have a specific question based on what you learn.

Comment: Even difficult for me, until I actually code it !

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize on two variables.

```
public class T1 implements Runnable {
    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();  

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // Your code here
                T2.LOCK.notify();
                T1.LOCK.wait();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
}

public class T2 implements Runnable {
    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public void run() {
        try {
            T2.LOCK.wait();
            while (true) {
            // Your code here
                T1.LOCK.notify();
                T2.LOCK.wait();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```