# How to make N Threads take turns in cyclic manner in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I recently went through this question on Stackoverflow, where problem is to print even and odd in two threads, in such a manner that they are printed in incremental order. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689449/printing-even-and-odd-using-two-threads-in-java/32919453#32919453), where I have provided one solution. This led me to think, what should we do, if we need N Threads to take turn in cyclical manner, in a predefined order ? I tried using CyclicBarrier for this. This is my code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class NThreadTurnTaking {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NThreadTurnTaking nThreadTurnTaking =  new NThreadTurnTaking();
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier =  new CyclicBarrier(3);
    NThreadTurnTaking.A  a = nThreadTurnTaking.new A(cyclicBarrier);
    NThreadTurnTaking.B  b = nThreadTurnTaking.new B(cyclicBarrier);
    NThreadTurnTaking.C  c = nThreadTurnTaking.new C(cyclicBarrier);
    Thread t1  =  new Thread(a);
    Thread t2  =  new Thread(b);
    Thread t3  =  new Thread(c);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();     
}

class A implements Runnable{
    private final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    public A(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        super();
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("A");
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
class B implements Runnable{
    private final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    public B(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        super();
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("B");
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
class C implements Runnable{
    private final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    public C(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        super();
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("C");
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want my program to print A->B->C in order. While using a CyclicBarrier does ensure that they are printed one after another, but the order is not being maintained, which is obvious, because I am not doing anything particular to tell my program that I want a specific order. This is the output :

> B
>   C
>   A
>   A
>   C
>   B
>   B
>   A
>   C.....

So, how do we ensure order here ? Kindly help.

Comment: If tasks need to execute in order one after another, the solution is to execute them on one thread. Then providing order is simple. The odd/even homework is just for learning some threading-techniques. From my point of view this requirement has no real-life significance. If a result vector needs to have an order, one would probably first collect all results and then sort them (or add them to a sorting datastructure).

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the clarification